# Using openLDAP groups to authenticate users for different services

Tags: authentication, attributes, openldap

I am currently setting up a small server with several applications. Since no Active Directory etc is planned, but I do need a centralized user administration, I decided for LDAP since all applications are capable of authenticating against it.

I have already set up a domain "dc=example,dc=lan". It has two organizational Units. Groups and Users. My plan was, to create a posixGroup for every application, so that a user can be added to each group (if he/she was allowed to use this application).

The structure would then be (example):

for each group

```
cn=ejabberd,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=lan
```

where cn=ejabberd is of type "posixGroup"

and for users

```
cn=user1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=lan
```

where cn=user1 is of type "posixAccount"

Some, but not all, applications expect the "mail" attribute as login name. Some don't.

My problem is, that searching for users in ou=users is easy as 1,2,3 - searching in "cn=ejabberd,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=lan" is sheer driving me crazy since the users are not a "child" to this group but a "memberuid" attribute. 
I have tried different filters and thought about another setup.. Just cannot think of anything different making sense right now.

Am I running down the wrong way, or maybe just blind to what's right in front of me? 
I'd be glad for any finger pointing out a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is, how I did it:

I created the following structure.

```
+dc=example,dc=com
 +ou=groups
 | +employees (PosixGroup)
 | +service1  (GroupOfNames)
 | +service2  (GroupOfNames)
 +ou=users
 | +user1     (User Account)
 | +user2     (User Account)
```

etc..

Groups like "service1" and "service2" are of type "GroupOfNames". Furthermore I had to install the "memberOf"-Overlay so I could search for this exact attribute of a user. 
This now gives me the possibility to tell each service to use a search filter that returns only the members of one special group, which will be granted access.  For instance, ejabberd will use this filter:

```
"(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberof=cn=ejabberd,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com))"
```

Found these informations on the following website. Just take care to set the filter case sensitive! "memberOf" will not return any results, since the overlay in this example uses "memberof".

http://www.schenkels.nl/2013/03/how-to-setup-openldap-with-memberof-overlay-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you're on the wrong track. You don't want to authenticate by application, you just want to define overall roles that users can be in. The applications can then be defined to require certain role(s) per application funtion, web page, etc. As a limiting case, an application can be a role, but if you set out to define it that way you're overly limiting yourself.

To answer your immediate problem, you only have to search under the `ou=Groups` item for `posixGroups` which have `memberUID={0}` where `{0}` is the DN of the user. In other words the search filter is

```
(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUID={0}))
```

Iterating those search results then gives you the DNs of all the groups of which he is a member.

Comment: Maybe I am getting you wrong. The applications that I want to authenticate against LDAP just leave me with a base which I can define and an additional filter. So searching for `memberUID={x}` doesn't seem to be possible.. Guess I start overthinking it..